# decompress string in c

Tags: c, string

I have a string like this :
h12pw3Bb4

I want decompressed to :
hhhhhhhhhhhhpwwwBbbbb

for numbers less than 10 i wrote this code but it isn't work for numbers greater than 10

```
for(int j = 0;j< strlen(txt);j++){
            if(isdigit(txt[j])){
                int x = txt[j];
                x = x - 49;
        
                while(x > 0){
                    printf("%c" , txt[j-1]);
                    x--;
                }
            }else{
                printf("%c" , txt[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Think what you need to do when you find the first digit in a sequence

Comment: `x-49` Please do not use such magic numbers. You want to convert the `char` value into a number. This can be done using character constants: `x-'0'-1`. This makes clear what you want and also works if the encoding is not ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See h12 implies print 'h' 12 times right. But you are reading character by character then when '1' is read 1 h will be print and next when 2 is read 2 h's are printed. So based on your code you are not going to achieve what you desire. You need to change it.

So, I think this should help:

```c
int st = 0;
for(int j = 0;j< strlen(txt);) {
    int x = 0;

    while(j < strlen(txt) && isdigit(txt[j])) {
        x = (x * 10) + (txt[j] - '0');
        j++;
    }

    x--;
    while(x > 0){
        printf("%c" , txt[st]);
        x--;
    }

    if (j < strlen(txt))
        printf("%c" , txt[j]);
    st = j;
    j++;
}
```

Assumptions :

1. The first number must be a letter.

Please change them accordingly to your requirements.

Comment: i know i have to changed! i don't know how i change code to work!!!

Comment: Okay, I'll try to change it and post it here

Comment: thanks. it has a small bug. when we enter h12p2Wb4 it doesen't print W that has no number

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: how can i change code that for number 1 that doesent need to present after a letter?

Comment: If there is no number after a letter, how many times you are expecting to print the letter? Like if input is W what should be the output?

Comment: just one time expected to print.example : if input is w3b output is wwwb

Comment: Edited it accordingly

Comment: thanks. but it isn't work for example like this: if input is h12pw3 it expected hhhhhhhhhhhhpwww but code print hhhhhhhhhhhhpw

Comment: Sorry, I have made a small mistake. I think it will work now

Answer (score 0):

Right, with multi-digit numbers you need several iterations of the loop before knowing the value of x.
So personally what I would do is this:

- define and initialize two variables `int x` and `char c` outside of the loop
- in the `if` block: calculate the value of `x` (multiplying it by 10 and adding `txt[j] - 49` ?)
- in the `else` block: print `c` `x` times, reset `x` to 0, set `c` to `txt[j]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think, your description does not match the `if` and `else` blocks from the author. You might provide a bit more details. Also be aware that `49` is ASCII code of `'1'`, not `'0'`. Adding up the digits will not work with that value.

Comment: Thanks :) Hmm, what I was trying to provide is the general steps (not C code) of an other algorithm that might solve the author's problem. Notice the question mark in my second item: I'm just trying to give ideas based on the original post, but I didn't try them out myself.

Comment: Wait, I don't quite understand why it doesn't match those blocks. Do you mean it wouldn't work with that condition ?

Comment: Oh, I misread a part. The if should work. But you must use `48` or `'0'` instead of `49` to make it work. Also I think the OP might not have sufficient knowledge to do what you suggest.